# Getting error of 'Column 'Attachments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.' when calling REST API

Tags: 2013, list, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, attachments

I have a list with 3 lookup columns and some of the items have attachments in it. I need to get the list items using REST API with details about any attachments in the items.

When I try to run the below query, I do not get any attachment details, though they are there.

```
http://<SITE>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<LISTNAME>')/items?
$expand=AttachmentFiles,Lookup1,Lookup2,Lookup3&
$select=Lookup1/Title,Lookup2/Title,Lookup3/Title
```

But when I try to run the query with additional select for `AttachmentFiles/FileName,AttachmentFiles/ServerRelativeUrl` it throws me error.

```
http://<SITE>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<LISTNAME>')/items?
$expand=AttachmentFiles,Lookup1,Lookup2,Lookup3
&$select=Lookup1/Title,Lookup2/Title,Lookup3/Title,AttachmentFiles/FileName,AttachmentFiles/ServerRelativeUrl
```

Below is the error message that I receive.

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
Column 'Attachments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update 1:**

I get same error with below query.

```
http://<SITE>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<LISTNAME>')/items?
$expand=AttachmentFiles,Lookup1,Lookup2,Lookup3
&$select=Lookup1/Title,Lookup2/Title,Lookup3/Title,AttachmentFiles
```

Comment: can you try it as `http://<SITE>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Narrative%20Framework')/items?
$select=Lookup1/Title,Lookup2/Title,Lookup3/Title,AttachmentFiles
&$expand=AttachmentFiles,Lookup1,Lookup2,Lookup3` and check ?

Comment: @GautamSheth: Tried it, but didn't work

Comment: sorry, Can you try it again as `http://<SITE>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Narrative%20Framewo‌​rk')/items?$select=Lookup1/Title,Lookup2/Title,Lookup3/Title,Attachments,Attachment‌​Files&$expand=AttachmentFiles,Lookup1,Lookup2,Lookup3`  and check ?

Comment: @GautamSheth: That worked! If you can post this as answer then I will be happy to accept it as answer Also why is `Attac‌​hment‌` required in select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `Attachments` column in the API.

Try it as below:

```
http://<SITE>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Narrative%20Framewo‌​‌​rk')/items
?$select‌​=Lookup1/Title,Looku‌​p2/Title,Lookup3/Tit‌​le,Attachments,Attac‌​hment‌​Files
&$expand‌​=AttachmentFiles,Loo‌​kup1,Lookup2,Lookup3
```

Comment: Getting "Column 'Attachments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." Using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-attached-to-list-items-by-using-rest)